# Different behavior between iPhone and iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad

I'm running the same code on an iPhone 6 plus and an iPad Pro and they don't react the same way.
A function is called when the device orientation change and then I'm just printing the width of the view with the following code :

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.vewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MyClass.rotated), name: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)
}
func rotated(){
    print(self.view.bounds.width)
}
```

On iPhone I get the width after the rotation but on iPad I get the width before the rotation.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Provide a bit more context. Post the whole method containing this print line.

Comment: You should look into the `traitCollectionDidChange(_:)` method which is called, among other cases, when a device is rotated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to get the width in the View Controller Function:

`func viewDidLayoutSubviews()`

Let me know if this helps!